# Transient analysis error(missing value) with OrCAD PSPICE 9.1

Tags: spice, circuit-analysis

I am new to PSPICE, and just tried an example given in the book I'm using (SPICE by Sedra/Roberts).

```
Transient Response of a Linear Network
* input signal source
Vi 1 0 SIN ( OV 10V 60Hz )
* linear network
R1 1 2 1
C1 2 0 2.65m
Rload 3 0 10
E1 3 0 2 0 10
*analysis*
.TRAN 1ms 50ms 0ms 1ms
.PRINT TRAN V(3) V(1)
.PLOT TRAN V(3) V(1) (-100,+100)
.end
```

When I run the simulation, I get an error :

```
* input signal source
Vi 1 0 SIN ( OV 10V 60Hz )
-------------$
ERROR -- Missing value
* linear network
R1 1 2 1
C1 2 0 2.65m
Rload 3 0 10
```

I tried changing the input signal line to `vi 1 0 sin ( 0V 10V 60Hz 0 0)` but the error persisted. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Should E1 be (2 0 3 0 10)

Comment: @Andyaka that would mean the VCVS is hooked up differently that wouldn't cause that error.  It is E +Node -node (+in -in) gain so the original is fine.

Comment: I checked you formatting in a manual, it appears fine.  You might try just changing Vi to VINPUT

Comment: @rawbrawb I thought on a VCVS input nodes came first d'oh!

Comment: @Andyaka which would make sense, I never rememberize those either.

Comment: Is that a "0V" (zero V) or an "OV" (oh V) in the "VI" line?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the line `Vi 1 0 SIN ( OV 10V 60Hz )`: you wrote `OV` rather than `0V`.

When it's replaced, this circuit simulates correctly (at least under ngspice).

Comment: I feel like the world's worst idiot now. Thank you so much for looking through it in enough detail to catch that!